# Swashbuckle Swagger Generator: StringBuilder out of Memory

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, aspnetboilerplate, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We have a fairly sizable ASP.NET Boilerplate .NET Core 3.1 project and Swashbuckle appears to run out of memory when generating the Swagger JSON.

We encounter the following error:

```
RequestAborted: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.. Request Path: /swagger/v1/swagger.json
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at System.IO.StringWriter.ToString()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.RespondWithSwaggerJson(HttpResponse response, OpenApiDocument swagger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Abp.AspNetZeroCore.Web.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtTokenMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseJwtTokenMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Naturally this indicates that the `StringBuilder` is not able to handle the size of JSON string. I'm not aware of any specific memory limitations of `StringBuilder` so not sure why this is failing.

Comment: StringBuilder is backed by an array chunks, when it calls `ToString` it tries to allocate into a string and is likely hitting the framework hard-limit of 2 gigs.  Note that this is likely not the actual problem, as it would be hard to image Swashbuckle generating that much json. Id say this is a bug or a design issue, maybe you should take this to github

Comment: @TheGeneral: I investigated that same angle and the whole JSON prior to encountering the issue was 1.7MB. Still troubleshooting this side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tracked the issue down and it had to do with the following method on our controller / app service.

```
public MyEnum GetMyEnum(MyDto myDto, long? someValue = null)
```

It appears the default parameter value was the cause. We were able to remove this dependency by marking the method as `private`.

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't debuge. How did you find the place of error?